# Rotate a control point of a curve path (not tilt)

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, transforms, path

I have a path like this:

[image]

I'd like to rotate the end point so the cross-section becomes like:

[image]

Is it possible?

Comment: does the endpoint have handles?  If not, you need to extend the handles before you can rotate the endpoint.

Comment: @MartyFouts ok, but how? I press V and set the handle type. But no handle for me regardless which one I choose. I checked viewport options, handles are set to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it's impossible to rotate a Path. You need to convert it to Bezier Curve via `Curve ‣ Set Spline Type`.